# ui-router 1.0 - can I prevent the creation of the component element?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm converting from ui-router 0.x to 1.0, and I would like to move from template/controller to modules.

A (legacy) route definition which includes this:

```
controller: 'widgetController',
templateUrl: 'widget.html',
controllerAs: 'vm'
```

results in the template being place directly in my view:

```
<div ui-view>
    <!-- template content here -->
</div>
```

however if I convert that controller/view to a component and route to that:

```
component: 'widget'
```

ui-router (or angular? not sure) is creating a DOM element for the component, so my html winds up looking like this:

```
<div ui-view>
    <widget>
        <!-- template content here -->
    </widget>
</div>
```

The extra  element is messing up my layout. I've seen some references to people trying to figure out how to most easily style that element to fix layout problems.

Can I prevent angular from creating the  element at all, while still using components?